Colon in the Table Name?
What does it mean when someone puts a colon in the table name?
Example:
Select *
from example_table:_filter_time AS st

What is the significance of the colon? I have never seen this used before in a SQL query like this.

This does not look like a valid PostgreSQL query. ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"


The only way that works  is if someone did a create table "example_table:_filter_time"(...) and you  wrote the query as Select * from "example_table:_filter_time" AS st. I'm pretty sure this is not the case. That leads to 2) This is some ORM nonsense leaking out.


Aside from the above, it could be that it's a dynamically constructed identifier and the author planned to pass that through something treating :_filter_name as a parameter placeholder, to end up with an example_table7, for example. Which some people do that way, not minding that might end up a SQL injection attack vector.

Ask the one who did it. It's a terrible naming convention, if any, and should imho not be allowed.

I'd say it is a typo - colon and underscore are next  to each other on the keyboard both with a shift - could be that shift and both keys were pressed unintentionaly. Otherwise this doesn't make sense.
